# Linking to a sharepoint List

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have attempted to write a piece of code linking to a sharepoint list (UtilitiesContracts) and bringing in certain columns (Client). However when I run the code it doesnt seem to link the data. Can anyone spot anything wrong with my code?

This is what appears when the code is loaded [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96N6l.jpg)

```html
<script src="https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
<!--SPServices Javascript-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<!--SpServices JavaScript get items from list 'files'-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var myQuery =
      "<Query>" +
      "<OrderBy>" +
      "<FieldRef Name='Client' />" +
      "</OrderBy>" +
      "</Query>";
    $().SPServices({
      webURL: "https://ext.kier.co.uk/teams/Utilities/",
      operation: "GetListItems",
      async: false,
      listName: "UtilitiesContracts",
      CAMLQuery: myQuery,
      CAMLRowLimit: 100,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        var liHtml = "<tbody>";
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
          liHtml = liHtml + " <tr><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Client") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title1") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title2") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title3")+ "</td></tr>";
        });
        liHtml += "</tbody>";
        $("#example").append(liHtml);
      }
    });
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "dom": 'Rlfrtip'
    });
  });

</script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Title1</th>
      <th>Title2</th>
      <th>Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run the code in the local computer HTML file.

You need add the code below into SharePoint page to make it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
<!--SPServices Javascript-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<!--SpServices JavaScript get items from list 'files'-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var myQuery =
      "<Query>" +
      "<OrderBy>" +
      "<FieldRef Name='Client' />" +
      "</OrderBy>" +
      "</Query>";
    $().SPServices({
      webURL: "http://sp2013/sites/team",
      operation: "GetListItems",
      async: false,
      listName: "UtilitiesContracts",
      CAMLQuery: myQuery,
      CAMLRowLimit: 100,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        var liHtml = "<tbody>";
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
          liHtml = liHtml + " <tr><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Client") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title1") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title2") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title3")+ "</td></tr>";
        });
        liHtml += "</tbody>";
        $("#example").append(liHtml);
      }
    });
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "dom": 'Rlfrtip'
    });
  });

</script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Title1</th>
      <th>Title2</th>
      <th>Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

[image]

If you want to access SharePoint list data from the local side, we can use CSOM(C#) to achieve it.

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Comment: So I need to put the code I have already done into a share point script editor?

Comment: Yes, you can add the code into Script Editor Web part or Content Editor Web Part or add it to page directly using SharePoint designer.

Comment: I am still getting no data into the table, is there something wrong with the way I am connecting to the list do you think?

Comment: You can use IE F12 developer tools to debug the code, and see if some error occurs.